# Edit text while playing a video in Premiere

Tags: premiere

Something I do to help me organize my timeline is typing out section descriptions, relevant quotes, and other information in text layers over my video. This is the easiest thing to do in Resolve, where you put a text layer over your video and then, in a separate panel, type what you want while you play the video. For a project that I have to edit in Premiere, I have 8 hours of interview to sort through, and I want to be able to type these descriptions in real time.

But it seems like I have two options: type what I want into the horrible text box in the program monitor, or use the Graphics tab in the Captions and Graphics panel, which overwrites everything you write as you write it if the video is playing. Both options require pausing the video, which sounds small but with this much footage that could end up costing me hours. Is there a way I can keep my workflow in Premiere?